# How to over ride a Laravel class with my own?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I am working with Laravel 5.2 and I trying to shift to SQS as my queue serice.

There was a bug in 5.2 in QueueSqs.php which was fixed here -> https://github.com/illuminate/queue/blob/5.6/SqsQueue.php in 5.6

Now I am not sure I can upgrade to 5.6 yet, because a lot of things are working with 5.2 and I don't want to break anything.

But I am sure I can somehow use this class in my code from 5.6 and tell Laravel to use it somehow. But I don't know how to.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked if this worked back in Laravel 5 or in class extends, but in newer versions Laravel generally tries to resolve the class from its container and by binding the original FQNS of the class to your your custom SqsQueue, it instead returns yours everytime the original is used:

```
class AppServiceProvider extend ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(\Illuminate\Queue\SqsQueue::class, function ($app) {
            return new CustomSqsQueue();
        });
    }
}
```

---

Well, actually, instead of overriding the original class and re-binding it for Laravel to use you could also add your own custom queue connector and use this instead of Laravels native SQS queue connector:

To add a new connector for the queue to use, open up a service provider and add the following code to the `boot`

```
public function register()
{
    $manager = $this->app['queue'];

    $manager->addConnector('sqs-custom', function() {
        return new CustomSqsQueue;
    });
}
```

Then, in the queue.php config, add a new connection based on the original SQS connection, but with the driver name you chose in the first parameter or `addConnector` in the service provider. The key of the array ist the name of the connection you use to define your queues:

```
'sqs-custom' => [
    'driver' => 'sqs-custom',
    'key' => 'your-public-key',
    'secret' => 'your-secret-key',
    'prefix' => 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id',
    'queue' => 'your-queue-name',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
],
```

Again, this is untested but should be able to work in Laravel 5.2.